# Select query not records any data when date is used in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table as below

```
 CREATE TABLE TEST
       (    TEST_ID NUMBER(9,0) DEFAULT NULL, 
        TEST_DESC VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
        TEST_DATE DATE);
```

I have inserted the data as follows

```
1   sample1 28-07-18
2   sample2 29-07-18
3   sample3 30-07-18
4   sample4 31-07-18
5   sample5 01-08-18
```

when I try to select the records from table TEST by using TEST_DATE as a where clause.

```
select * from TEST where TEST_DATE = '01-08-18'
select * from TEST where TEST_DATE = TO_DATE('2018-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
```

the above queries returning empty set as output.
Please help me out in this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you seeing the values inserted in the DB? because format for `DATE` is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava yes I'm able to see the values as DD-MM-YY in DB

Comment: share with your dbfiddle link

Comment: Have you tried just `where TEST_DATE = '2018-08-01'`

Comment: Could you post the output of `select to_char(TEST_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') from test where test_id = 5`?

Comment: SELECT * FROM `TEST` where TEST_DATE = "2028-07-18" 
have you try this one.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava tried `where TEST_DATE = '2018-08-01'` got error ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: @Ashishya11 select to_char(TEST_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD') from test where test_id = 5 output 2018-08-01

Answer (score 1):

`Date` type in Oracle also stores the time. So probably your query doesn't work because of different time parts.
Use this query to get the full view of the `Date` values:

```
SELECT TEST_ID, TEST_DESC, TO_CHAR(TEST_DATE, 'yy.mm.dd HH24:MI:SS') FROM TEST;
```

Answer (score 0):

could be due to the NLS settings in your database, 
do a select * from test and see how the output is.

then either change your NLS settings for update your query accordingly to match that.

[image: select * from test[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xV1V.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try adding TRUNC:

```
select * from TEST where trunc(TEST_DATE) = trunc(TO_DATE('2018-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Comment: `trunc(TO_DATE('2018-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))`  can be simplified to `TO_DATE('2018-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: `TO_DATE('2018-08-01','YYYY-MM-DD')` can be further simplified to `DATE '2018-08-01'`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use `date` constants.  So:

```
where TEST_DATE = DATE '2018-08-01'
```

If this doesn't work, then you probably inserted data from another century and you should fix the data.  You can try this:

```
select extract(year from test_date), t.test_date
from t
where extract(year from test_date) < 2000
```

You can fix the data in place (by adding years) or by re-importing the data.

So, use four-digit years.  That is what the year values are.